# Update a value in a array in php

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [messagecount] => 1
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [status] => returnCode
                    [messageid] => messageId
                    [to] => to
                    [client-ref] => client-ref
                    [remainingbalance] => remaining-balance
                    [messageprice] => 0.01
                    [network] => network
                    [errortext] => error-message
                )

        )

)
```

What I want to do is that I want to Replace the value in the ['messageprice'] it is set to 0.01 by default I want to make it 0.02 or any other I want.

After editing I want updated value in the same array. I want this result

```
Array
(
    [messagecount] => 1
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [status] => returnCode
                    [messageid] => messageId
                    [to] => to
                    [client-ref] => client-ref
                    [remainingbalance] => remaining-balance
                    [messageprice] => 0.02
                    [network] => network
                    [errortext] => error-message
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do like

```
$yourarray['messages'][0]['messageprice'] = '0.02';
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/91703)

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm not clear. I want to replace the ['messageprice'] value in the same array

Comment: @ProfessorHaseeb That's what the above code does... (though I wouldn't have quoted the value). Did you even try it?

Comment: The solution do the job

Comment: @ProfessorHaseeb, See the Demo in the answer.